# Free File Explorer alternative with dark theme for Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, file-management, dark-theme

I don't like the white background in File Explorer. I know about the custom theme patchers for installing custom themes but I don't want to use them for my work computer. I don't like the built-in dark themes. They are way too dark. Also I am stuck with Windows 7. I know that Windows 10 anniversary edition will have a complete nice dark theme.

So my option now is to use a File Explorer replacement. 
Any free ones with a dark theme? It should at least have the basic features. Copy, move, delete and rename files and folders. I don't care about ones I seldom use. I can always use the regular file explorer for those. Price maybe up to $20.

Answer (score 4):

There are many explorer replacements for Windows. My personal favourite is [Q-Dir](http://www.softwareok.com/?seite=Freeware/Q-Dir). It does everything standard explorer does, and a few more features. Q-Dir is my favourite because it supports many view layouts, my personal favourite is quad mode. It is easier than having to open up 4 standard explorers and switching between them. There are other alternatives like FreeCommander and whatnot, but I'll let others take the credit for them.

The still white parts are system themes, and a custom themer is required to change them. I left it on the default theme so you can mix and match custom themes on your own.

[image: my qdir layout]